# Reading a file over the network from an mvc.net web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have deployed my mvc4.5 web app to Server1 in my network

Is there a way to access/read data from FileA.zzz that sits on Server2 in my Network from my mvc4.5 web application?

For example, in my Model, I want to read a file, by pointing to "x:\folder1\folder2\FileA.zzz"

x is a mapped drive that points to Server2

Currently I'm getting an error saying the file is not accessible

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please provide stack trace and sample code. But my first guess would be that your app does not have permissions. Is it running under network account?

Comment: you are absolutely right, the app doesn't have permissions. I'm not sure how to verify what it's running under. The webApp is deployed under my IIS 7.5; it uses "windows authentication" as this is an internal website, which is only accessible to our Active Directory Users. As for the Stack Trace, this is really not my app. It's a colleague of mine that I'm trying to help. I would've put the entire info in that file in a proper DB structure. I'll get you more info tomorrow. Thanks! :)

Comment: Could you please share how this code is written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Your web application uses application pool to run. Application pool has identity (user account that is used to run application.) You need to change identity of your application pool to user that has required permissions. By default your app will use default app pool. Use IIS Manager to update that.

Instruction about how to do it you can find here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523018(v=bts.10).aspx
Procedures

> To configure the credentials for the default application pool  1.
>   Click Start, then Settings, and click Control Panel.
>
> 2. In Control Panel, double-click Administrative Tools.
> 3. In Administrative Tools, double-click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
> 4. In Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager, expand (User account) and click Application Pools.
> 5. Right-click DefaultAppPool and click Advanced Settings to display the Advanced Settings dialog box for the application pool.
> 6. Modify the identity for the application pool by clicking the ellipsis (…) button next to Identity under the Process Model section
>      of the Advanced Settings dialog box.
> 7. In the Application Pool Identity dialog box, select the Custom Account option, click Set, and specify an account that has access to
>      the BizTalk Server databases. Click OK until you exit the Advanced
>      Settings dialog box.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! We resolved the issue by using "UNC" path rather than the "mapped" drive my colleague was using ;-)